# Can't set a variable from a Fetch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-custom-search

I'm having problems returning a variable from the following fetch:

```js
var CSE="";

    async function checkEngine(engine) {
                    const response = await fetch(engine);
                    const json = await response.json();
                    CSE = await "" + Object.keys(json)[0];

                    console.log(CSE);
                }

                for (i = 0; i < engines.length; i++) {
                   checkEngine(engines[i]);
                    console.log(CSE + " ");

                    if (CSE != "error") {
                        CSE = engines[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (CSE == "error") iframe.src("status.html?text=Search Limit Reached&color=red");
```

Comment: I guess you'll need to add `await` before `checkEngine(engines[i]);`

Comment: as @dshung1997 suggested, you need an await keyword there and also wrap that in a try catch block.